# How to get logged in user data as a object from "angularx-social-login"?

Tags: angular

I tried to sign in function with google, facebook authentication using angularx-social-login package, it's also works and display the user data like name,profile picture. I want to get that user data as object to store globally.

here's my function

```
signInWithGoogle(): void {
try{
  this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  localStorage.setItem('userObject', JSON.stringify(this.user));
  console.log(this.user)
  //this.router.navigateByUrl('/profile');
}
catch(err){
   console.log(err)
}}
```

Here's ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.authService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
  this.user = user;
  this.loggedIn = (user != null);
}); }
```

Comment: can you please share the code how to get the user info?

Comment: yes I updated the question block, this.user print as "Undefined"

Comment: It's already return a JSON object.

Comment: You can store user response directly

Comment: yes but I get the data from localstorage and print that its say undefined.

Comment: ok thanks I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the user information in ngOnInit function after subscribe. Try with below code,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
        localStorage.setItem('userObject', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.user = user;
        this.loggedIn = (user != null);
    });
}

signInWithGoogle(): void {
    try{
        this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: yes brother it's works, thank you so much to save my day.

Comment: It's okay no problem dear